# Material Design - Creating on click ripple - Animation at point of click

Tags: jquery, html, css, material-design

Firstly, here's the link (click on any of the tiles): http://www.google.com/design/#resources

I've gone through the code

```
 <svg width="100%" height="100%" overflow="hidden">
  <defs></defs>
    <g>
      <ellipse cx="27.5" cy="189.46875" rx="20" ry="20" stroke="none" fill="white" class="ripple" fill-opacity="0.5" style="-webkit-transform: scale(1); opacity: 0;">
       </ellipse>
    </g>
 </svg>
```

On click, at the point of click the above ellipse is generated.

Can anyone help how to create it at the point of click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`event.pageX`](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageX/) and [`event.pageY`](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageY/) to find the mouse coordinates in the event handler.  Use those values to position the circle.

[jsfiddle.net/pu8jX](http://jsfiddle.net/pu8jX/)

Comment: Extending @gilly3's answer - You could try it out with a specific (button) element http://jsfiddle.net/pu8jX/27/

Answer (score 2):

**This is the best example I've found, I hope they serve!**

http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/ripple-click-effect-google-material-design

Other Amazing Lib is Waves: Click effect inspired by Google's Material Design

http://publicis-indonesia.github.io/Waves/

Answer (score 1):

I created a plugin for this, it is available on github for you to grab https://github.com/ninox92/Google-material-design-ripple-effect/

preview on : http://thomasreynders.com/google-material-design-plugin/

Comment: Nice Plugin and good presentation, but the text blinks when the ripple appears, there must be a bug in chrome. Thank you.